# wakanda database query error when testing in bootstrap.js

Tags: wakanda

I created a new project in wakanda studio 1.1.3, then I created a model called Users with one attribute email of string type.

I passed on a query in my bootstrap.js to check if i am getting any value from the database.

The query command is the following

```
ds.Users.query({select: "email"});
```

The model is global access

When i run this is my console i am getting an error

> "Some error occurred while parsing:     
>   503 - Service Unavailable  body { margin: 0px;
>   padding: 0px; font: 90% "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
>   } div#title { background-color: #2c4b79; padding: 15px 15px 15px 20px;
>   margin: 0px; } div#message { padding: 20px; } div#details { padding:
>   10px; } h2 { color: #fff; font-size: 1.3em; margin: 0; padding: 0; } p
>   { padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
>
> ### 503 - Service Unavailable
>
> "

Can anyone help in this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use your bootstrap.js file for testing purposes. Create a new file that is not bootstrapped (ex. test.js, serverside.js, ...) and run (Run Button) a valid query (http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda-Server-Side-Concepts/Programming-in-Wakanda-Server/Queries-and-Finds.300-720609.en.html) in that file. You will then see the output in the output area:

**Query Example:**

```
ds.Users.all();

ds.Users.query('ID > 0');

ds.Users.query('ID > :1', 0);
```

**Inside Wakanda studio:**

[image]